# Look for multiple patterns with string.gsub

Tags: string, lua, gsub

I'm working on a graphing program and the function of a line needs to be printed to the screen.  However, if a math function is in the line's function (ex:)

```
function(x) return math.atan(x) end
```

then I want to remove the 'math.' part.  I also want to remove any spaces in the function, as well as other patterns I may think of in the future.  This is what I currently have (simplified, of course)

```
local func = "math.atan( x )"
print(func:gsub("[math%. ]", "")) --look for math. or a space
--OUTPUT: n(x)
```

I realize I don't need the spaces in-between the parenthesis, but those are there just for testing purposes.  I was hoping for the output to say "atan(x)"

Comment: Your pattern matches the individual characters `m`, `a`, `t`, `h`, `.`, and space, not `math.`. There's no way to do this without multiple calls to `gsub`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is just to chain a bunch of gsub calls together. In this case, you could use

```
local func = "math.atan( x )"
print(func:gsub("math", ""):gsub("%s", "")) --> atan(x)
```

You could write a shorthand method to hide the gsub chaining if you really want to even:

```
local function chainremove(source, ...)
    for index, value in ipairs({...}) do
        source = source:gsub(value, "")
    end

    return source
end
```

Which could make your concept of "other patterns [you] may think of in the future" as a single method call on the surface:

```
local func = "math.atan( x )"
print(chainremove(func, "math", "%s"))
```

If you do add patterns later, do remember to escape your percent signs.